# Database design for "alternate" names with master reference

Tags: database-design

What would be the best practice to store alternate names for entities and link them to a "master" record for rolling up data?

For example, I have a list of companies;

```
id name
1  Orange Kid Industries
2  Apple Kid Inc.
5  O.K.
```

Company `5 O.K.` is an alternate name for `1 Orange Kid Industries`. These companies need to be stored discreetly so that if a child record *needs* to be tied to 5 and not 1, (in the interest of storing historical data if the company name changed for instance,) it can.

I need to tie `5 O.K.` back to `1 Orange Kid Industries` as the "master" record so, when looking at all children of `1 Orange Kid Industries`, I see all children of 1 and 5 combined.

I'm leaning toward a required master ID for all records. If a user creates a new company `6 Moldy Orange Kid Industries`, he can assign it a master ID of 1 to signify that this is just another name for `1 Orange Kid Industries`.

```
id name                        master
1  Orange Kid Industries       1
2  Apple Kid Inc.              2
5  O.K.                        1
6  Moldy Orange Kid Industries 1
```

This seems to be the simplest route without requiring much redundant data. Are there any downsides to this approach?

Comment: The Stack Exchange Q&A format is not suitable for questions asking for opinions. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a good solution to me.  The only think I might change is to leave master null if a record is it's own master.  Probably not a huge deal, but seems like a potential infinite loop pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would normalize the data.  A company master table and a company names table end a company names table that would have foreign key to the company master table.  I would also avoid nulls and any logic based on nulls enforce foreign key constraints.  The null mean you do not know.

Comment: Would you suggest storing company name in both the master table and names table? So that the same name could possible be in both tables?